# crm.ckeditor.js not found

Tags: drupal, ckeditor

Inside /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Resources.php
Line 738 and for civicrm version 5.3.1

```
 $editor = Civi::settings()->get('editor_id');
    if ($editor == "CKEditor") {
      CRM_Admin_Page_CKEditorConfig::setConfigDefault();
      $items[] = array(
        'config' => array(
          'wysisygScriptLocation' => Civi::paths()->getUrl("[civicrm.root]/js/wysiwyg/crm.ckeditor.js"),
          'CKEditorCustomConfig' => CRM_Admin_Page_CKEditorConfig::getConfigUrl(),
        ),
      );
    }
```

I get error event configuration page which is as follows:
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED and url which is not loaded is as shown below
https://newspace/prestige/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/js/wysiwyg/crm.ckeditor.js
So link is incorrect which seems to be due to incorrect [civicrm.root],

Can I set $civicrm_root in civicrm.settings.php and can that help fix it?
When I place directly the url it works but it is in the code below which is Core part of civicrm

Answer (score 3):

You can write the below code in `civicrm.settings.php` file to override the current value of `[civicrm.root]` token.

```
global $civicrm_paths;
$civicrm_paths['civicrm.root'] = array(
  'url' => 'https://website_url.com/.../civicrm',
  'path' => '/path/to/civicrm/folder/',
);
```

Similarly, it can be used to set `[civicrm.files]` and `[cms.root]`.