# CiviCRM CK editor trying to access Skins.js, and CSS resources from the Drupal 8 core assets instead of the Civi directories

Tags: ckeditor, drupal-8

So I'm having a weird issue where when trying to create a new mailing or event. The wysiwyg editor does not show up, instead the html editor appears as blank. There are errors in console (404 errors) where the page is trying to load ckeditor/skins/moono/skin.js. However, it is trying to load it from the web root via the Drupal core.(['web_root']core/assets/vendor/ckeditor/skins/moono/skin.js)

This is the same with other assets like the editor.css file.

Naturally these assets do not exist in the Drupal core ck-editor directory. Is there a way to direct these to the Civi resources (that do exist) or fix these error.

I ran into this after fixing the Error name not resolved error with crm.ckeditor.js.  I followed the guide steps in this Civi stack exchange here.

[crm.ckeditor.js not found](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/25922/crm-ckeditor-js-not-found?rq=1)

This allowed for the crm.ckeditor.js script to be found, but now it cannot find the aforementioned  assets. Which previously were not being loaded or called.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem.  It happened ~95% of the time but not 100% of the time, leading me to believe there's a race condition present.  It started when I upgraded from Civi 5.12.1 to 5.12.3, but you experienced this problem sooner and I'm guessing it's tied to Drupal 8.6.15.  It also happened on my test site but not my dev site (haven't pushed to the live site yet for obvious reasons).

I was able to solve it by uninstalling/reinstalling the core `ckeditor` module via `drush`.  However, I'm not sure *why* that fixes it, but I've been unable to trip the issue.  In my debugging, it certainly seems that Civi's CKEditor is loading the paths of the Drupal CKEditor.  I'm not sure why though.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the install process for drupal 8 currently involves copying some things to the libraries folder. If you used the composer method (https://gitlab.com/roundearth/drupal-civicrm-project) it gets handled mostly automatically, but you might still need to set some settings in civicrm.settings.php. See https://hq.megaphonetech.com/projects/commons/wiki/CiviCRM_for_Drupal_8_installation_notes

Comment: Our Organization did not use the round-earth installation, I can check with a colleague who set it up on how exactly he set it up. However, At present the components it is trying to call from the Drupal core are located in web/libraries/civicrm/bower_components/ckeditor. I tried to make the changes to the civicrm.settings.php file in the link you provided, but this caused other components to not be found.

Comment: It sounds like it might be a composer-based install, so maybe all you need to do is copy the other components. The old manual method had a script at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/drupal/issues/9 which should still work to copy the other components to libraries, just maybe make a backup of libraries/civicrm in case something gets overwritten you don't want overwritten.

Comment: I ran the script in the link your provided and set the web root to {cms.root]/libraries/civicrm. To no avail Civi still tires to access components from cms.rootcore/assets/vendor/ckeditor/skins/moono/editor.css, cms.root/core/assets/vendor/ckeditor/styles.js"  and cms.root/core/assets/vendor/ckeditor/skins/moono/editor.css

Comment: If you go to admin - system settings - directories, then click the blue question mark icon in the green description area at the top it will display what it thinks you have. That might provide a hint.

Comment: My  cms root looks fine, to confirm my civiroot should look like this?
[civicrm.root] web.root/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core

Comment: Does it say "web.root" literally or is that a file system folder? And/or is stackexchange messing up the brackets? Were you able to set the four lines in civicrm.settings.php as described in https://hq.megaphonetech.com/projects/commons/wiki/CiviCRM_for_Drupal_8_installation_notes?

Comment: Sorry, Its var/www/site/web as web.root.  I followed your steps, and it is still looking in web/core/assets not under libraries/civicrm. despite me defining it in civicrm.settings like in your link.

Comment: Maybe try posting in https://chat.civicrm.org in the drupal channel. It seems like it might need some more in-depth troubleshooting and is a better place for back-and-forth.